# Indicator library - Rendering based on value, min and max

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, dashboard, indicator

For dashboards, I need to render values in different ways: traffic light, progress bar, speedometer, gauge, etc.

Is there a JavaScript library that already does that - offer a choice of indicators/graphics with the output based on the value/min/max?